# Does Telerik require RadControls to be installed for development?

Tags: c#, winforms, reference, telerik, rad-controls

Here's the situation:

I'm on a team developing a large WinForms application.  When Telerik released the 2013 Q2 release, we upgraded.  Some of the changes caused errors in our program.  So we rolled back to the Q1 installation and decided to upgrade in a controlled environment.  So we got an extra computer, installed the new RadControls release and fixed all the issues.  Now we're attempting to test on another computer, and we're getting errors.  Everything works fine on the computer with the new version installed.  When you try it on a computer with out the latest version, it crashes.

We're using TFS for source control, and the references are pointing to DLLs included in the source control, so I know that the references are pointing to the Q2 DLLs.  Also, if I move `C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik`, the program works fine (on the same computer where it was already working).  Therefore, I know that there are no hidden references to the DLLs in `Program Files`.

My question boils down to this:  in order for those DLLs to work properly, is it required that RadControls be installed on a machine and for the installed version of RadControls to be the same version as the one in the build?

Maybe RadControls is pointing to some system thing that happens when you install the Q2 stuff.  I really don't know how it all works behind the scenes.  I'm just shooting in the dark now.

Answer (score 1):

No, installation is not needed for the assemblies to be working and simply referencing the correct assemblies should allow you to run the project. Basically, setting the CopyLocal to true of the Telerik assemblies and copying the bin folder to another machine without installation should work with no issues.